# kafka consumer with confluent-kafka-go change offset

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-go

I create a new consumer with this configuration:

```
c, err := kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
                 "bootstrap.servers": addresses,
                 "group.id":          "my_group",
                 "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
         })
topic := "testTopic"
if err = c.SubscribeTopics([]string{topic}, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Then I produce events based on the following code and consume one event:

```
events := []map[string]string{
{                                     
        "name":       "Foo",
},                                                 
{                                                  
        "name":       "Bar",                                                       
},                                                 
}                                                          
                                                                                                    
err = p.ProduceEvent(events[0])//there is a wrapper to produce events       
err = p.ProduceEvent(events[1])                                    
                                                                                   
res, err := c.ReadMessage(100 * time.Second)                                              
time.Sleep(20 * time.Second)                                                       
                                                                                                              
c.Close()
```

when I describe the group with
 `watch /home/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my_group  --describe`. The results in each step is:

1. after producing the events:
   [image]
2. when I consume one event:
   [image]
3. after closing the consumer:
   [image]

I can't understand why finally the lag is zero! I just consumed one events. It's weird behaviour to me, that `Close` would be change the offset. Any clue is appreciated.

Comment: @MickaelMaison my question is this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReadMessage` wraps `Poll`. [`Poll`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-go/index.html#Consumer.Poll) gets a batch of messages and buffers them locally. Since you have configured your consumer to auto commit offsets, it will commit all the fetched messages, even the ones that are locally cached and that your application has still not processed. That is why you see that there is no lag after closing the consumer.

`librdkafka` (and thus `confluent-kafka-go`) does not have a way to configure `max.pool.records` so if you want to control exactly which offsets get commmited, you'll need to disable auto commit offsets and commit them manually using `StoreOffsets`: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/380#issuecomment-539903016

Comment: thanks for your info. Do you know any go pkg which support `max.pool.records`? Or I should handle the offset.

Comment: not really, I would probably just handle the offsets myself. You can follow this example: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/blob/master/examples/consumer_example/consumer_example.go